# OpenGL object not scaling properly

Tags: c++, matrix, opengl, transform, glm-math

I want to scale a triangle with a model matrix. I have this code:

```
void Triangle::UpdateTransform()
{
    
    mView = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f));
    mModel = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(2.f));
    mModel = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), mLocation);
    mMVP = mProj*mView*mModel;
}
```

With this code I get no results.
But if I change the order of the scale and translation:

```
    mView = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f));
    mModel = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), mLocation);
    mModel = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(2.f));
    mMVP = mProj*mView*mModel;
```

I get a very weird result: [result(triangle should be at the center)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyfmD.png)
I have no idea what is causing this, maybe it has something to do with the orders.
I'd really appreciate some help.
My vertex shader:

```
#version 410 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

uniform mat4 u_MVP;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_MVP * position;
};
```

Comment: Why do you set `mModel` and then overwrite it? In the first case the scale is overwritten and in the second case the translation is overwritten. Most likely, the translation will move the model out of view.

Comment: How could I set the mModel's scale and translation without overwriting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st argument of [`glm::scale`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#ga05051adbee603fb3c5095d8cf5cc229b) and [`glm::translate`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#ga1a4ecc4ad82652b8fb14dcb087879284) is the input matrix. These functions define a matrix and multiply the input matrix by the newly specified matrix.
In both cases, you specify the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) (`glm::mat4(1.0f)`) for the inout matrix. You have to pass `mModel` as the input matrix. e.g.:

```cpp
mModel = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), mLocation);
mModel = glm::scale(mModel, glm::vec3(2.f));  // <-- mModel instead of glm::mat4(1.0f)
```